# CakePHP Routing: Changing pretty URLs site-wide

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Let's say I want a page to have a pretty URL:

**Config/routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

If I want to send visitors to that page, I can use the URL like:

```
$this->redirect('/profile');

$this->Html->link('Your Profile', '/profile');
```

But let's say I change my mind and I now want the URL to be:

```
/account
```

How can I change the entire site without changing every instance of `/profile` to `/account`?

**Alternatively...**

Another way to ask my question would be how can I properly code all URLs using Cake array syntax (which I prefer to do rather than hardcode anything):

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));

$this->Html->link('Your Profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

And then ensure that any time that controller/action combination is called, it sends people to the URL:

```
/profile
```

And have this rule in one place that can be changed. Something like:

```
Router::connect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'), '/profile');

// Later change to

Router::connect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'), '/account');
```

Is there any way to do that, and also allow further request parameters to be passed along to be added to the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the routing documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

In your `app/routes.php` add:

```
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

Now you can create your links like this:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Link to profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

Or if you want to allow additional parameters:

```
// When somebody comes along without parameters ...
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
// When somebody parses parameters
Router::connect('/profile/*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

And then you will be able to do something like:

```
$userId = 12;
echo $this->Html->link('Link to other profile', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile', $userId));
```

The `$userId` will then be available in the controller via:

```
echo $this->request->params['pass'][0];
// output: 12
```

This way you can easily change the url's of your website without having to change every single view/redirect or what so ever. Please bare in mind that you should not change your controller names! Because that will mess up a lot. Choose wisely ;-)

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Comment: @MukeshKumarBijarniya I'm glad I could be of any help :)